# Find a version of @mui/icons-material that will work with Node v11.15.0

Tags: node.js, npm, material-ui

I have this package installed to my Node application but am getting this error:

> error @mui/icons-material@5.4.2: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">=12.0.0". Got "11.15.0"

Is there a version of `@mui/icons-material` that would work with Node 11.15.0?

Comment: Why are you still using Node 11? Odd-numbered versions never get LTS support, you _should_ move to at least 12 (see https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/).

Comment: I raised this before but ultimately, it's not my call. For now I just have to work with 11.15.0 as best I can.

Comment: Then you'll have to go pawing through the MaterialUI releases or changelog to find when they dropped Node 10 support, but frankly it seems like a false economy to help you solve this quickly; the time it takes should be another datapoint (along with the number of unpatched vulnerabilities you'll likely get as a result) illustrating why this is the wrong decision to whoever _can_ make that call.